# Access a specific element inside a Mat matrix using openCV

Tags: java, opencv, face-recognition

I'm working on the java opencv and implementing a eigen face recogniser by converting matlab code. One of the things that is really confounding me, is how to access elements inside the mat. For example I have this mat -

```
Mat tempImage = Imgcodecs.imread("C:\\Fraps\\ImageSet\\img.bmp");
```

Now say I want to access the second column of this matrix. When I try,

```
tempImage.get(1,2);
```

I get header meta data instead of the actual elements. If I try -

```
tempImage.col(1);
```

Instead of accessing the second column, I again get a whole bunch of header info again. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: I've never use opencv before, but why do you expect a 2D matrix? What about color channels? Looks like load operations often specify color flags.

Comment: "... implementing a eigen face recogniser by converting matlab code" - what a horrible idea. at least use opencv's [PCA functions](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#PCACompute(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat))

Comment: I realise it is reinventing the wheel but I need to understand the underlying matrix functions and how they are being changed.

Comment: please, when using opencv from java, stick with higher level functions. i do not see, where you would need per-pixel-access at all. (and it is usually a very bad idea using get() and put())